# Best practices for configuring a server?

Tags: server, linux

I am on linux-root server and has just installed a wp 4.1 final.

Aditionally some few Amazon-Web-Services-Plugins - such as:

- amazon-link
- amazon-product in a post
- scrapeAzon

*Note: I've tested all the necessary keys and passwords*

About the php-confgurations:

- curl is enabled
- curl_exec is enabled

Conclusion; wp 4.1 does not fetch any information from amazon. The keys are okay: I've tested this with the amazon-scratchpad.

Addtional JI get the following issues - seen in the dashboard:

> RSS Error: WP HTTP Error: Could not resolve host: planet.wordpress.org; No data record of requested type
>
> PHP Warning: php_uname() has been disabled for security reasons

I have installed the [Query Monitor-plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/query-monitor/) (Monitor: Monitoring of database queries, hooks, conditionals and more.)

I found some more things:

> query_cache_size is set to 0 (null or zero! )

What can I do now?

Comment: I'm going to go ahead and ask, what's a linux-root server?  And what is your specific question?  That the amazon web services plugin doesn't work?  Are you experiencing any issues with a basic, vanilla WordPress install (no plugins and one of the default themes)?

Comment: "Linux-root server" - I'd guess he means a server that he has root access too, as opposed to shared hosting.

Comment: rup is right - sorry for being not clear here.